# How to make JS function wait for JSON data to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This works:

```
function getDataJSON() {
    var queryString = "https://www.examplesite.com/someJSON.json";

    $.getJSON(queryString, function(data) {
        doStuffWithData(data)
    });
 }

 function doStuffWithData(JSON) {
     // some code that refers to JSON
 }

 getDataJSON();
```

But this complains that a variable (JSON) is undefined somewhere in doStuffWithData():

```
function getDataJSON(callback) {
    // Gets share data and runs callback when received
    var queryString = "https://www.examplesite.com/someJSON.json";

    $.getJSON(queryString, function(data) {
        if(typeof callback === "function") {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
 }

 function doStuffWithData(JSON) {
     // some code that refers to JSON
 }

getDataJSON(doStuffWithData());
```

What am I likely to be doing wrong? The $.getJSON() call takes a second or two so I do need to wait for that and do stuff after it. I think the issue is with the code execution order, but it could be that I've misunderstood how to properly pass the data to the callback function.

It would be better if I could just load the data into a variable all my other functions can access.

Comment: Just to clarify - I am trying to avoid needing to call doStuffWithData() inside getDataJSON()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
getDataJSON(doStuffWithData());
```

should be this:

```
getDataJSON(doStuffWithData);
```

Otherwise it invoked that function immediately and attempts to pass the result of the function into getDataJSON

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave out the parenthesis in this call 
`getDataJSON(doStuffWithData());` should be `getDataJSON(doStuffWithData)`. The reason is that doStuffWithData is the function and doStuffWithData() is the retrun value from the function.